# Inner div pushes paragraph outside outer div

Tags: html, css

[image]I have a div called insidenextcontent2.
This is just a div that colors a section.
In this div I have another div called bottle1, which is a geometrical shape(supposed to be the top of a bottle). 
Also, I have a paragraph which I want to position besides this geometrical shape. However, the paragraph is placed below the whole div(insidecontent).

How can I fix this? I want the text to be inside the outer div, besides the inner div.

```css
.insidenextcontent2 {
  margin-top: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  background: #EEFA0F;
}

.bottle1 {
  margin-left: 30%;
  border-top: 97px solid black;
  border-left: 35px solid transparent;
  border-right: 35px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 150px;
}

#webpara {
  color: black;
  margin-left: 50%;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="insidenextcontent2">
  <div class="bottle1"></div>
  <p id="webpara">Web &amp app development</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want it to the left or right of you inner div?

Comment: you forgot to close the `bottle1 div` tag.

Comment: Stavm yes, but it still does not work

Comment: I'm just taking a guess at what you're trying to accomplish. Here's a [codeply project](https://www.codeply.com/go/F4nj14sjmA). I can explain more if this is the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. place your paragraph in a div alongside the bottle div.
2. add `display: flex` to your containing div.

https://jsfiddle.net/m08paL1d/2/

```
<div class="insidenextcontent2">
    <div class="bottle1"> </div> 
    <div>
      <p id="webpara">Web app development</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.insidenextcontent2 {
    margin-top: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15%;
    background: #EEFA0F;
    display: flex;
}

.bottle1 {
    margin-left: 30%;
    border-top: 97px solid black;
    border-left: 35px solid transparent;
    border-right: 35px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 150px;
}

#webpara {

    color: black;
    margin-left: 50%;
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Why do I need flex? And why should I need to put the paragraph inside a another div